# Instant Run is not supported on devices with API levels 20 or lower using Blue Stack emulator

Tags: android, bluestacks

I have downloaded Android studio and Bluestack Emulator. However, the default device provided by Bluestack is of `API 19(Samsung)`

When I try to run the code there is an error message:

```
"Instant Run is not supported on devices with API levels 20 or lower."
```

How can I get a higher API emulator device or make the instant run go... ? I am just learning Android development so I am not concerned with what API I build in... I  just want the program to run so that I can move on with coding something new.

Comment: Use the official [Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html) or try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). Read FAQ and troubleshooting first if you run into any problems. Or disable Instant run since it has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: If bluestack don't provide a newer Android version then there's not a lot you can do. The best option though is to use the Official Android Emulator as part of the Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio on Mac. You can go to Preferences/Instant Run/ and disable all selections.